# Separating column using separate (tidyr) via dplyr on a first encountered digit

Tags: regex, r, string, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to separate a rather messy column into two columns containing *period* and *description*. My data resembles the extract below:

```
set.seed(1)
dta <- data.frame(indicator=c("someindicator2001", "someindicator2011",
                              "some text 20022008", "another indicator 2003"),
                  values = runif(n = 4))
```

## Desired results

Desired results should look like that:

```
          indicator   period    values
1     someindicator     2001 0.2655087
2     someindicator     2011 0.3721239
3         some text 20022008 0.5728534
4 another indicator     2003 0.9082078
```

#### Characteristics

1. Indicator descriptions are in one column
2. Numeric values (counting from first digit *with* the first digit are in the second column)

## Code

```
require(dplyr); require(tidyr); require(magrittr)
dta %<>%
  separate(col = indicator, into = c("indicator", "period"),
           sep = "^[^\\d]*(2+)", remove = TRUE)
```

Naturally this does not work:

```
> head(dta, 2)
  indicator period    values
1              001 0.2655087
2              011 0.3721239
```

### Other attempts

- I have also tried the default separation method `sep = "[^[:alnum:]]"` but it breaks down the column into too many columns as it appears to be matching all of the available digits.
- The `sep = "2*"` also doesn't work as there are too many 2s at times *(example: **2**003**2**006)*.

---

What I'm trying to do boils down to:

- Identifying the first digit in the string
- Separating on that charter. *As a matter of fact, I would be happy to preserve that particular character as well.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this might do it.

```
library(tidyr)
separate(dta, indicator, c("indicator", "period"), "(?<=[a-z]) ?(?=[0-9])")
#           indicator   period    values
# 1     someindicator     2001 0.2655087
# 2     someindicator     2011 0.3721239
# 3         some text 20022008 0.5728534
# 4 another indicator     2003 0.9082078
```

The following is an explanation of the regular expression, brought to you by [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tC4pM1/1).

- `(?<=[a-z])` is a positive lookbehind - it asserts that `[a-z]` (match a single character present in the range between a and z (case sensitive)) can be matched
- `?` matches the space character in front of it literally, between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
- `(?=[0-9])` is a positive lookahead - it asserts that `[0-9]` (match a single character present in the range between 0 and 9) can be matched

Comment: Thanks, this amazing, it [seems to be](https://regex101.com/r/tC4pM1/2) matching the results correctly and thanks very much for the explanation. It crossed my mind that solving this may involve *lookbehind/forward* but I don't find them easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `unglue::unnest()` :

```r
dta <- data.frame(indicator=c("someindicator2001", "someindicator2011",
                              "some text 20022008", "another indicator 2003"),
                  values = runif(n = 4))

# remotes::install_github("moodymudskipper/unglue")
library(unglue)
unglue_unnest(dta, indicator, "{indicator}{=\\s*}{period=\\d*}")
#>       values         indicator   period
#> 1 0.43234262     someindicator     2001
#> 2 0.65890900     someindicator     2011
#> 3 0.93576805         some text 20022008
#> 4 0.01934736 another indicator     2003
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>